# Notice: Undefined index: page in

Tags: indexing, themes, undefined

I get this Notice on the back-end of my wordpress website
Notice: Undefined index: page in /customers/f/e/4/pointdevue-plus.be/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/SliderResponsiveTheme/settings.php on line 17
When I take a look at line 17 I see this code :
(from line 14 to 21)

```html
);
function mytheme_add_admin() {
    global $themename, $shortname, $settings_list;
    if ( $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) ) {
    
        if ( 'save' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {
                  foreach($settings_list as $value) {
                    //echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $value . '");</script>';
```

Does somebody knows what's exactly wrong and how to fix this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test existence of key with `isset`:

```
if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) ) {
    ^^
```